# Issues in the 'Fabcar' tutorial when bringing up a Kafka-based ordering service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I've brought up a Kafka-based ordering service in the Fabcar network by modifying some docker composition/configuration files, which is one of the tutorials on Hyperledger Fabric readthedocs.

These are the issues I've suffered from. Could you please tell me how to resolve them or even one of them?

1. I'd like to have containers start up in a specific order with 'wait-for-it.sh' script so that the orderer starts trying to connect to the Kafka cluster right after it is ready to perform commands. Do you happen to know how I should apply the script to my docker composition file?
2. When I executed "enrollAdmin.js" file in order to register an admin account with node enrollAdmin.js on the network in the same way as I did on the unmodified network,

[This error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dm5wT.png) is shown and it doesn't work:

```
~/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_nodules/fabric- 
client/lib/Client.js:746
        async _createOrUpdateChannel(request, have_envelop) {
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier
  at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
  at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/home/~/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/index.js:25:18)
  at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

I took a look at Client.js file and was trying to understand how it works, but I have no idea what it is for and why it causes the issue.

Please help me resolve this issue if you know how.

Answer (score 0):

Update Your nodejs .
check node version

```
node -v
```

It shoulb be greater than 8.0.0.

Comment: I've worked on the 1.0 version of Fabric and it says nodejs should be 6.9.X for 1.0v of Fabric. Should I update my nodejs?

Comment: yes, update it... async keyword has come after verion 8.0.0

Comment: OK. Thank you for your help! Let me update nodejs and try again!